# Problems with postgresql, c# and windows server 2019

Tags: c#, windows, postgresql

I have a very strange problem, I have an application that connects to a local server with postgresql, the application is programmed with visual studio 2019, c # and npgsql driver, what the application does is ask for the time zone of a column timestamp from the database. So far so good, it gives me time zone values ​​-3 and -4 which is what I expect. Then I take the same application with the same framework, version of the postgresql server and driver, but when I run this on the server that has windows server 2019 it always returns the timezone with value 8 no matter what I do, the time zone of my computer and windows server 2019 are the same and both are located in the same country, the operating system of both is updated to the latest version.

This is the code for the main method of the class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PgSqlConnection pgSqlConnection1 = new PgSqlConnection();
        pgSqlConnection1.Host = "127.0.0.1";
        pgSqlConnection1.Port = 5432;
        pgSqlConnection1.UserId = "postgres";
        pgSqlConnection1.Password = "230169";
        pgSqlConnection1.Database = "biotime";

        pgSqlConnection1.Open();

        PgSqlCommand command = pgSqlConnection1.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now())/3600.0 as zona;";

        PgSqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        PgSqlDataAdapter adaptador = new PgSqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

        adaptador.Fill(tabla);


        Console.WriteLine(tabla.Rows[0][0].ToString());


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

I'm using DEVART connector form postgresql but same issues with NPGSQL

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some baseline misunderstanding of PG time storage here. Timestamps in Postgres do not "store a timezone" so you can't get PG to "give you a stored timezone".

With respect to datatypes:

`timestamp` stores whatever time you give it, or whatever time it is in whatever timezone the db is set to if you use `now()` as the value. If you give it a time of '15:00' it stores 15:00. If you give it a time with an offset such as 15:00-0500, it discards the offset and stores the 15:00. If it's 3pm in Chicago right now and you told the db it lives in Chicago, and you insert `now()` then 15:00 is stored.

When you ask for it back the time you get is the time as stored, even if you changed the timezone of the db since

- the column is a timestamp
- the db is in -8 (in a location that doesn't observe DST, to make things simple) and you store the time 15:00 (either by inserting a value '15:00' or by using the now() function when it's exactly 3pm in a -8 zone)
- querying the db reports the time as 15:00
- you change the db to a -5 (non DST) zone
- querying the table still gives the time as 15:00

`timestamptz` takes whatever timestamp with offset you give it and converts it to UTC. If you get the time from `now()` then the time is the current time in the declared zone, converted to its UTC equivalent. The UTC time is stored. The offset you provided (or the offset of the timezone active at the point you used the `now()` function) is NOT stored. When you ask for it back the db converts the stored time according to the currently configured zone and presents it as the time in that zone

- the column is a timestamptz
- the db is in -8 (non DST) and you store the time 15:00 (either by inserting a value '15:00' or by inserting a value '15:00-0800' or by inserting a value '16:00-0700' or by inserting a value '17:00-0600' or by ... or by using the now() function when it's exactly 3pm in a -8 zone)
- querying the table gives the time as '15:00-0800' (even if you inserted '16:00-0700' it is stored as '23:00+0000' and converted to '15:00-0800' upon query because the db is in -8
- you change the db to a -5 (non DST) zone
- querying the table now gives the time as '18:00-0500'; same moment in time, same stored value of '23:00+0000', different presentation

So, `EXTRACT TIMEZONE FROM somestoredtimestamp` is really just a synonym for "what is the applicable offset of this stored moment, in the timezone you're set to?", it's not extracting a *timezone* from anything - it's giving an offset from UTC for that time in the current known timezone. If the db is set to Chicago (observes DST) then you'll get -5 or -6 out of it depending on what time of year the date is. If the db was set to a location that didn't observe DST then you'd get a consistent offset out of it regardless the date. *Offsets are not time zones* so "extract timezone" is a misnomer.

---

The time zone PG uses can be set in a variety of places - the PostgreSQL config file, the TZ environment variable, the connection string, per session by SET TIMEZONE TO ..., or it might even use the windows control panel region settings if it wasn't set anywhere else

You're getting +8 from your EXTRACT TIMEZONE command because PG believes it lives in a zone that is +8 and has no DST (like Singapore)

Comment: ok, I also read the same documentation regarding the timestamp not saving the time zone, but coincidentally the data is returned correctly, because here in my country the time zone is changed 2 times a year (winter and summer time ) the last change occurred on September 5 and the query reflects it in the data.